# why is php trim is not really remove all whitespace and line breaks?

Tags: php

I am grabbing input from a file with the following code

```
$jap= str_replace("\n","",addslashes(strtolower(trim(fgets($fh), " \t\n\r"))));
```

i had also previously tried these while troubleshooting

```
$jap= str_replace("\n","",addslashes(strtolower(trim(fgets($fh)))));
$jap= addslashes(strtolower(trim(fgets($fh), " \t\n\r")));
```

and if I echo $jap it looks fine, so later in the code, without any other alterations to $jap it is inserted into the DB, however i noticed a comparison test that checks if this jap is already in the DB returned false when i can plainly see that a seemingly exact same entry of jap is in the DB. So I copy the jap entry that was inserted right from phpmyadmin or from my site where the jap is displayed and paste into a notepad i notice that it paste like this... (this is an exact paste into the below quotes)

"

バスにのって、うみへ行きました"

and obviously i need, it without that white space and breaks or whatever it is.

so as far as I can tell the trim is not doing what it says it will do. or im missing something here. if so what is it?

UPDATE:
with regards to Jacks answer

the preg_replace did not help but here is what i did, i used the 
bin2hex() to determine that the part that "is not the part i want" is
efbbbf
i did this by taking $jap into str replace and removing the japanese i am expecting to find, and what is left goes into the bin2hex. and the result was the above "efbbbf"

```
echo bin2hex(str_replace("どちらがあなたの本ですか","",$jap));
```

output of the above was efbbbf
but what is it? can i make a str_replace to remove this somehow?

Comment: What's that `addslashes` for? And please don't say it's for the database.

Comment: Did you try just `trim($str)`, without the second parameter? As per the [manual](http://php.net/trim), your version won't remove NUL bytes and vertical tabs (whatever a "vertical tab" is...)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trim unicode whitespace in PHP 5.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166896/trim-unicode-whitespace-in-php-5-2)

Comment: bfavaretto, yes as you see above the 2nd line of code that i tried only has the first parameter.
mario, the addslashes it to add slashes mainly just to entries that will contain a "'" because some will have that in my case.

Comment: Did you check if it's a non-breaking space, as the "possible duplicate" link suggests?

Comment: just tried all the examples in the link mario posted, but i still am getting the same result as i posted.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `trim` function doesn't know about Unicode white spaces. You could try this:

```
preg_replace('/^\p{Z}+|\p{Z}+$/u', '', $str);
```

As taken from: [Trim unicode whitespace in PHP 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166896/trim-unicode-whitespace-in-php-5-2)

Otherwise, you can do a [`bin2hex()`](http://www.php.net/bin2hex) to find out what characters are being added at the front.

**Update**

Your file contains a UTF8 BOM; to remove it:

```
$f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
$s = fread($f, 3);
if ($s !== "\xef\xbb\xbf") {
    // bom not found, rewind file
    fseek($f, 0, SEEK_SET);
}
// continue reading here
```

Comment: the preg_replace did not help but here is what i did, i used the 
bin2hex() to determine that the part that "is not the part i want" is
efbbbf
i did this by taking $jap into str replace and removing the japanese i am expecting to find, and what is left goes into the bin2hex. and the result was the above "efbbbf"
    echo bin2hex(str_replace("どちらがあなたの本ですか","",$jap));

Comment: @user1397417 think I found it. your file contains a UTF8 BOM header. Updated my answer.

Comment: Your updated Solution looks like it has solved my problem, thanks! I would have click "this answer was useful" for you but it said it requires "15 reputation" sorry

Comment: @user1397417 no worries, I've given you +5 by up voting your question ;-) welcome to SO!