# Wrong result for array_count_values in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

I have an array like this -

> Array ( [0] => একটু [1] => আরো [2] => নয় [3] => কাছে [4] => থাকো [5] => না [6] => কাছে [7] => ডাকো [8] => না [9] => আরো [10] => কাছে [11] => আজ [12] => দুজনের [13] => প্রথম [14] => মিলনের [15] => চাঁদ [16] => তারা [17] => ঐ [18] => সাক্ষী [19] => আছে [20] => তুমি [21] => আমার [22] => আমি [23] => তোমার [24] => [25] => মন [26] => যে [27] => ভরেছে [28] => জোছনা [29] => ঝরেছে [30] => পৃথিবী [31] => দ্যাখো [32] => ঐ [33] => ঘুমিয়ে [34] => পড়েছে [35] => মন [36] => যে [37] => ভরেছে [38] => জোছনা [39] => ঝরেছে [40] => পৃথিবী [41] => দ্যাখো [42] => ঐ [43] => ঘুমিয়ে [44] => পড়েছে [45] => আমি [46] => তোমার [47] => তুমি [48] => আমার [49] => একটু [50] => আরো [51] => নয় [52] => কাছে [53] => থাকো [54] => না [55] => কাছে [56] => ডাকো [57] => না [58] => আরো [59] => কাছে [60] => আমি [61] => তোমার [62] => তুমি [63] => আমার [64] => [65] => ফুলেরই [66] => হাসিতে [67] => হাওয়ার [68] => বাঁশিতে [69] => এ [70] => রাত [71] => শেখালো [72] => ভালো [73] => যে [74] => বাসিতে [75] => আমি [76] => তোমার [77] => তুমি [78] => আমার [79] => একটু [80] => আরো [81] => নয় [82] => কাছে [83] => থাকো [84] => না [85] => কাছে [86] => ডাকো [87] => না [88] => আরো [89] => কাছে [90] => তুমি [91] => আমার [92] => আমি [93] => তোমার [94] => )

When i am counting the same values using the following code it is giving wrong results like below -

```
$wordCountArr = array_count_values($matchWords);
```

> Array ( [একটু] => 1 [আরো] => 6 [নয়] => 3 [কাছে] => 6 [থাকো] => 3 [না]
>   => 6 [ কাছে] => 3 [ডাকো] => 3 [ আজ] => 1 [দুজনের] => 1 [প্রথম] => 1 [মিলনের] => 1 [ চাঁদ] => 1 [তারা] => 1 [ঐ] => 3 [সাক্ষী] => 1 [আছে] =>
>   1 [ তুমি] => 2 [আমার] => 5 [আমি] => 2 [তোমার] => 5 [] => 3 [ মন] => 1
>   [যে] => 3 [ভরেছে] => 2 [জোছনা] => 2 [ঝরেছে] => 2 [ পৃথিবী] => 2
>   [দ্যাখো] => 2 [ঘুমিয়ে] => 2 [পড়েছে] => 2 [ মন] => 1 [ আমি] => 3 [তুমি]
>   => 3 [ একটু] => 2 [ ফুলেরই] => 1 [হাসিতে] => 1 [হাওয়ার] => 1 [বাঁশিতে] => 1 [ এ] => 1 [রাত] => 1 [শেখালো] => 1 [ভালো] => 1 [বাসিতে] => 1 )

But why [কাছে] => 6 and [ কাছে] => 3 ??? It suppose to be [কাছে] => 9
Now should i trim the spaces before and after or match words with spaces ? I used `array_map('trim',$matchWords)` but no luck!
How can i fix this? Please HELP !

Comment: trim removes spaces at the beginning and/or end of a string, not in the middle; you might use str_replace for that; but for UTF-8, I'd recommend using preg_replace instead

Comment: Used $matchWords = preg_replace('/[\s\t\r\n]\+/iu', '', $matchWords); But not helping !

Comment: `trim` is a single byte function and would not work in this case. You need to use a multi byte trim function (which PHP does not have, but there is help to be found on [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php), see the comments).

Comment: If you don't have white space, then you're probably suffering from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931204/what-is-normalized-utf-8-all-about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the matching is separate for those because of the space. `trim()` to remove spaces for each word wouldn't work for your case as it doesn't remove unicode white spaces.

So your solution use: [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Refer:

[Trim unicode whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166896/trim-unicode-whitespace-in-php-5-2)

[why is php trim is not really remove all whitespace and line breaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859098/why-is-php-trim-is-not-really-remove-all-whitespace-and-line-breaks)

Comment: $matchWords = preg_replace('/^\p{Z}+|\p{Z}+$/u', '', $matchWords);
Used this but still the same problem !

Comment: $matchWords = preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','',$matchWords);
Works with this ! Thank you for the reference @Menon

Comment: You may use this too: `$str = preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','',$str);` and
`$str = preg_replace('/\s+/u', '', $str);`