# php: how to remove starting blanks and new lines

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a string,

```
"

     it is a dog"
```

How to remove the starting blanks and the new lines?
The output should be:

```
"it is a dog"
```

I have tried `preg_replace("/^\s*/ms", "", $string)`, but not works.

Comment: Did you try the trim command of PHP?

Comment: `echo trim(" it is a dog");`

Comment: just use trim($string);In your case use ltrim($string).

Comment: If trim not working then look here,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166896/trim-unicode-whitespace-in-php-5-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

examples from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
$text   = "\t\tThese are a few words :) ...  ";
$binary = "\x09Example string\x0A";
$hello  = "Hello World";
var_dump($text, $binary, $hello);

print "\n";

$trimmed = trim($text);
var_dump($trimmed);

$trimmed = trim($text, " \t.");
var_dump($trimmed);

$trimmed = trim($hello, "Hdle");
var_dump($trimmed);

$trimmed = trim($hello, 'HdWr');
var_dump($trimmed);

// trim the ASCII control characters at the beginning and end of $binary
// (from 0 to 31 inclusive)
$clean = trim($binary, "\x00..\x1F");
var_dump($clean);
```

The above example will output:

```
string(32) "        These are a few words :) ...  "
string(16) "    Example string
"
string(11) "Hello World"

string(28) "These are a few words :) ..."
string(24) "These are a few words :)"
string(5) "o Wor"
string(9) "ello Worl"
string(14) "Example string"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try ltrim [(http://php.net/ltrim](http://php.net/ltrim)).

Comment: Notice that my answer is about ltrim and not about trim. The author did not ask for trim, but did for ltrim (since he/she only wanted to remove the starting whitespace). As rekire also mentioned, remove the second parameter. It is set to all whitespace by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', trim($string));
```

Comment: this will remove all the new lines, not only the starting new lines.