# PHP Array Output Variable different from that shown in an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

The following array when printed shows that the value of $career[2] is 2010-.

However no matter what I try, this if equation will not trigger. Can these array variables be different in some way?

```
echo $career[2];

    if($career[2] == "2010-"){
        $career = $career[1];
    }
```

A print_r of the array $career reveals this..

```
 Array ( 
[0] => BIS career 
[1] => CEO of the corp 
[2] => 2010- 
[3] => Leader of R&D 
[4] => 2005-10 
);
```

VAR DUMP

```
    array(11) { 
[0]=> string(316) "BIS career " 
[1]=> string(194) " CEO of the corp " 
[2]=> string(163) " 2010- " 
[3]=> string(160) " Leader of R&D " 
[4]=> string(165) " 2005-10 " }
```

Comment: what you want to do with your peace of code can you tell?

Comment: Instead of `print_r()` try `var_dump()` It might be possible that it contains space `2010-` .OR Try `if(trim($career[2]) == "2010-")`

Comment: Maybe a whitespace at the end of the string...

Comment: Var Dump is giving me this... string(31) " 2010- "  Trim does not seam to fix it.

Comment: Can you post your actual array var_dumped

Comment: Posted the var dump .

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
echo "...".$career[2]."...";
```

it will reflect the space

Try:

```
preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','',$str);
```

reference: [Trim unicode whitespace in PHP 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166896/trim-unicode-whitespace-in-php-5-2)

Comment: Var Dump is giving me this... string(31) " 2010- " Trim does not seam to fix it.

Comment: as taken from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166896/trim-unicode-whitespace-in-php-5-2, try: preg_replace('/^[\pZ\pC]+|[\pZ\pC]+$/u','',$str);

Comment: Robin its hard to do with looking into the actual string, can you try http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and share it, also try: strpos to search for "2010-", to see what you get in return, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: I've found it. Although the string did not show any html when doing strpos I found it still contained tags. I have removed them with strip tags function. Baffling