# MySQL Wrong Order by varchar

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, utf-8

I created a page with an ACP and save my data there. Everything runs without problems. But suddenly I have a mysterious problem. In the public area I always output the data alphabetically, but an entry ("Damaged Goods") is always ranked last.

My command to select:

```
SELECT lyric_id, lyric_title, lyric_lang_00, lyric_text_00, lyric_lang_01,   
       lyric_text_01, lyric_lang_02, lyric_text_02, lyric_lang_03, lyric_text_03, 
       lyric_lang_04, lyric_text_04, lyric_lang_05, lyric_text_05 
FROM dnd_lyrics 
WHERE lyric_text_00!='' OR lyric_text_01!='' OR lyric_text_01!='' OR   
      lyric_text_02!='' OR lyric_text_03!='' OR lyric_text_04!='' OR 
      lyric_text_05!='' OR lyric_text_03!='' ORDER BY lyric_title ASC"
```

My command to insert:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO dnd_lyrics (lyric_title,lyric_lang_00) 
  VALUES('".$db->str($_POST['lyric_title'])."','".$db->str($config['lang'])."')");
```

Affected database:
https://syntaxhigh.normanhuth.com/FlniL9

So far, the problem has only occurred with this one entry. And if I enter it manually via phpMyAdmin, it works.

Comment: Maybe there's a space or some other character before the name? What are some other records? What does `var_dump` show? You also are possibly open to SQL injections with this code.

Comment: having a look at your data, i can see a mystery character before the

**​Damaged Goods**

looks like a possible control character, that's the issue. depending on the encoding is shows up as `â€‹`

Comment: `â€‹` I can't see this. :O

Comment: switch to ansi encoding

Comment: OK. Thanks. I take the autocolplete content from a other table with the tracks names and there have a few cols the same problem. 
Now I must search there. Thank You.

Comment: Don't splay an array across columns -- make another table.

Comment: `â€‹` is Mojibake for "ZERO WIDTH SPACE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested your data and your query, and got this result:

```
. . .

|        8 | World War 3                        |
|       79 | W​+​J                              |
|       88 | ​Damaged Goods                     |
+----------+------------------------------------+
```

Notice the alignment of the right bars. There are non-printing spaces in the data. On my screen, it looks like:

```
. . .

|        8 | World War 3                        |
|       79 | W ​+ ​J                              |
|       88 | ​ Damaged Goods                     |
+----------+------------------------------------+
```

The "Damaged Goods" title has an extra non-printing space at the beginning, which makes it sort after all other titles.

If I open your data in vim, I see:

```
(88, '<200b>Damaged Goods', 'en',
```

Unicode 200b is "zero width space": https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm

You should do some kind of whitespace-trimming operation on your data before inserting it to the database. Unfortunately, the reglar PHP trim() function doesn't do the job.

See [Trim unicode whitespace in PHP 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166896/trim-unicode-whitespace-in-php-5-2) for a solution.

---

Re your comment:

Your use of `trim()` function in PHP won't work. The PHP `trim()` function understands only ASCII whitespace characters, not unicode whitespace-like characters. See http://php.net/trim for the list of characters trim looks for.

Comment: I built the trim function directly into the MySQL class
return $this->link->real_escape_string(trim($string));

Comment: Trim unicode whitespace in PHP 5.2 is the solution for me. Thanks.

Comment: Hex('W​+​J') = 57 E2808B 2B E2808B 4A (with some spacing added)

Answer (score 0):

There really is a sign in the database that is not visible right away. Probably during the first tests with Javascript/Ajax.

Bill Karwin's tip helped.
I added the "[Trim unicode whitespace in PHP 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166896/trim-unicode-whitespace-in-php-5-2)" function to my MySQL class.
And which simply run through the tables in a loop and rewrite the contents with this function and thus get the database clean.

Thanks for your help.