# Convert/replace U+2009 character with space

Tags: php, html, decoding

I have a string that contains unreadable space character:

[image]

How can I replace this character with a normal space so I can get a string like: `"a b c d"`

I have tried this:

```
$str = utf8_decode($str);
```

But it converts that character to question mark `?`

Comment: The accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807948/trim-unicode-whitespaces-php should help.